# What is the big O of a nested loop when the inner loop is of variale length?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, while-loop, big-o, nested-loops

What is the time complexity of this?

The outer loop is O(log n). But I am not sure about the inner loop? Is it O(log n) also? Would that make this entire algorithm O(n log n)?

```
while (n > 0) {
   for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      /* O(1) code */
   }
   n = n / 2;
}
```

Comment: Don't analyze the loops separately. Together they have `n + n / 2 + n / 4 + n / 8 ...`.

Comment: @jabaa n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1 = 2*n - 1

Comment: You can say that this works in O(n). Which means in time complexity always O(2*n - 1) is O(n)

Comment: you can look here too https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612966/show-that-2n1-is-o2n

Answer (score 3):

Nope inner loop is **O(n)**

inner loop is decreasing to n/2 each step of while.

so this code runs in O(2n - 1) which is
n + n/2 + n/4 + n/ 8 + 1 = 2*n - 1
and you can say it just **O(n)**

```
while (n > 0) {  // O(logn)
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) { // O(n)
     /* O(1) code */
  }
  n = n / 2;
```

}

Comment: Notice the `n` variable is changed on each iteration

Comment: @Berthur yes you are right. I edited my answer. that is O(2*n - 1)

Comment: O(2n-1) == O(n)

Comment: @ThomasSablik that is exactly true. In time complexity O(2n) means O(n)

Comment: That has nothing to do with time complexity. O(n) always equals O(2n-1), unrelated whether we're talking about time complexity, memory or apples. That's math.

Comment: The count 2*n - 1 is only correct when n is a power of 2

Comment: @ThomasSablik yes you are right. (big-O notation)[https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bigOnotation.html]

Comment: *"O(2n - 1) which is n + n/2 + n/4 + n/ 8 + 1 = 2*n - 1"* sounds like O(2n - 1) can only be one function. This is upside down.